# Get the id of the ajaxLink button before submission

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, yii

I have created an ajax link(CHTML::ajaxLink) in Yii framework(not ajax form submit button) that passes some value to a controller via ajax. There are multiple link which passes different value to the controller. I want to get the id/class attribute of the clicked link before the value is passed to the controller(in "beforeSend" of the jquery.ajax options ). Simply i just want to get the id/class attribute that generated the ajax request. Help!!!

UPDATE::Here's the code

```
echo CHtml::ajaxLink ("Click Here",
                              Yii::app()->createUrl('default/del/id/6'), 
                              array(
                                    'beforeSend' => 'function(){
                        //I want to get the id of the link here     
    }',
                                    'complete' => 'function(){
                            }',

                                    'update' => '#loadContent'),

        );
The above code will generate the following a tag:-
<a href="#" id="yt1">Click Here</a>
```

When the user click the above link, i want to get the id (yt1) in the beforeSend part of the 
ajaxLink.

I tried the below code:

```
 'beforeSend' => 'function(){
 $("a").click(function(){
    var a = $(this).attr("id");
    alert(a); 
 }
```

The above code works but the id is alerted only when the link is clicked twice. On the third click, the id is alerted twice and keeps on increasing on subsequent clicks. I dont have any clue about this strange problem.

Comment: In the click handler you can do `$(this).attr('id')` or `$(this).attr('class')` to get id or class.

Comment: If you don't want to fumble with the jquery, you could generate your links so that the id and class are parameters in the link (i.e. GET requests)

Comment: You're getting the multiple alerts because you're registering a new click handler on links each time in the beforeSend.  In reality, you should instead define a 'data' key in your ajax array, where you set a JSON key:value with something like {key1: $(this).attr('id')}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`$.proxy()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/), to change the context of the function to anchor tag from the current ajax object:

```
'beforeSend' => '$.proxy(function(jqXHR,settings){
        console.log($(this).attr("id"));// or alert($(this).attr("id"))
        // rest of your function
        // you can still use the jqXHR object, and the settings map to manipulate the ajax call
},this)'
```

**Edit:**

Let me tell you why the number of alerts is growing on subsequent clicks.

This is happening because each time you click, there is a new click handler getting associated to the `<a>`, because of this line:

```
$("a").click(function(){...})
```

So when you click the first time, the order of function calls is:

```
beforeSend callback
assign click handler (1)
```

So there is no alert yet.

Second time:

```
1st click handler's alert
beforeSend callback
assign click handler (2)
```

Third time:

```
1st click handler's alert
2nd click handler's alert
beforeSend callback
assign click handler (3)
```

And so on as it keeps increasing.

**Edit2**:

Alternative and better, you can use `context` option to make the context, the link that was just clicked:

```
'context'=>'js:this', // right now 'this' is link, so we can pass it
'beforeSend'=>'function(){// i would suggest using the signature 'function(jqXHR,settings)' so that 
    // you can modify the ajax call if you need to

    console.log($(this).attr("id"));// or alert($(this).attr("id"))
    // rest of your function
}'
```

From [jquery's ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> By default, the context is an object that represents the ajax settings used in the call ($.ajaxSettings merged with the settings passed to $.ajax).

**Edit3**:

Another alternative: Pass the id of link as an additional setting key:

```
'idOfLink'=>'js:$(this).attr("id")',
'beforeSend'=>'function(){
     // now you can access the id like:
     console.log(this.idOfLink);// or alert(this.idOfLink)
}'
```

Comment: i know you have accepted an answer, but i don't think it's the correct one(imho). so let me know how this works out for you, and ask for clarifications if you have trouble implementing/understanding this solution, or other feedback.

Comment: please also check my new edit, i explained why your code is not working, let me know if you need clarifications

Comment: btw, my code will also give you the id of the link in the first click! also please tell me why you think this answer doesn't help you. i have taken out time and tried to answer, so please leave some feedback, if you don't mind

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification about the alert. Now i have a clear idea about my problem. I didn't use the code you provided because I couldn't figure out the proxy and jqXHR thing. But your explanation has been really helpful to me, so I'm accepting your answer.

Comment: Btw, I solved my problem using html5 localstorage. I stored the id of the link on onclick event and used it in the ajax beforesend part.

Comment: when jquery is executing the ajax's `beforeSend` callback function, the context of the function-is within the ajax object, and not the link tag, i.e $(this) within the function points to the ajax object and not the link tag. So if we change this context to the link, we can access the properties of the link tag. The callback function is anyway always passed the jqXHR object and also the settings map of the ajax object, so we can use those to do additional things with the ajax object if we wish, and we also have passed the link, therefore we can access link also. my point is that (continued)

Comment: (continued) you don't need a click handler, you don't need local storage. but of course it is your code, your project, you should do it the way you want.

Comment: now i get it, I used your code and works perfectly!!! and its a lot cleaner than using localstorage. Thank you so much.......You are good in jquery......

Comment: you are welcome, glad i could help, and thank you for the kind words. in the future, please remember to ask for clarifications if you don't understand something. it'll help everyone in the process.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `jQuery` you can do this to get the element attribute: `$("#element_id").attr("id")` or if you're using `HTML5`, you can use the `data` tag on your link, like:

```
<a href="bla.php" data-name="your_data_here">Link</a>
```

And also using `jQuery` you do this: `$("#element_id").data("name")`

Comment: Your code works but I'm unable to get the id on first click of the ajax link. Anyways thanks for the answer. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to elaborate more / post code fragments so that we can have a better idea about your problem. But from what you explain here, I assume that you want whatever processing your Ajax request to know which link originated it. Assuming the asynchronous processing is done somewhere else (outside your browser), it wouldn't have access to your DOM. Therefore, you need to embed the id as an argument in your ajax request. In other words, pass the id of element sending the request as part of the request.

Comment: I need to get the id of the link before the ajax request is send to the server. I have added the code.